# Changing ActiveRecord timezone for a session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timezone

I've been trying to change the timezone for a user session using the Time.zone method. I get the correct date and time when I do Time.zone.now but when I do a select query using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all, the datetime columns in the result are always in UTC. What do I need to do so that all the select queries return data in the timezone that was set using the Time.zone method, without changing the views? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to convert the Time to the local timezone with ruby.

```
Time.now.in_time_zone()
```

use it as such.

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('Alaska') # => Fri, 31 Dec 1999 15:00:00 AKST -09:00
```

You can give the function a timezone string, or an UTC offset

http://apidock.com/rails/Time/in_time_zone

Comment: I know I could do that but I am looking for a way to get the timezone offset applied directly in the query results so that I don't have to change all my views. Is that possible?